# Как загрузить две сборки разных версий?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть библиотеки разных версий:

1. Name = "MyLibrary", Version = 1.2.0, publicKeyToken=null
2. Name = "MyLibrary", Version = 1.8.1, publicKeyToken=NOTNULL
   Как их загрузить и вместе использовать?

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, в чём именно смысл данной манипуляции?

Comment: Хочу проверить, что библиотеки работают одинаково на больших данных. По отдельности запускать приложение не вариант

Comment: Делаете два (или больше) проекта в одном солюшене. К каждому проекту подключаете свою версию библиотеки. / Загружаете сборку с помощью `Assembly.Load*`.